# Alternative solution to ESRI's Geometric network for wet Infrastructure

Tags: geometric-network, pipe-network

I'll be glad for some help with "market research" on GIS for water pipes networks
what are the differences between these solutions in compere to ESRIs geometric network

[GHydraulics](http://epanet.de/ghydraulics/index.html.en)

[WaterCAD V8i](http://www.bentley.com/en-US/Products/WaterCAD/)

[WaterGEMS V8i](http://www.bentley.com/en-US/Products/WaterGEMS/)

are they based on graph and connectivity table ?, do they allows flow simulation and finding the nearest valve (isolation trace) ? is there any more solutions ?

Comment: Not my *forte* but you might also consider plain PostGIS functions such as this network walking example: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2010/07/network-walking-in-postgis.html

Comment: Depends what purpose you want to use them for. The cost (cash or time to learn) and ability to carry out tasks is different for each. Please expand on your intended use. Otherwise just learn GHydraulics / EPANET and go from there.

Comment: right now i'm working with ESRI.  I'm looking for effective and good solution that CAD operators can learn fast and not very expensive.